# How to update only the library project in Angular

Tags: angular, angular9, angular11

My main project has been already been upgraded to 11 but our library project still pointing to 9 version.

I have tried with the below commands for updating the library but when I verify the package.json(file of library) still it points to 9.

ng update "**LibraryName**" @angular/core@11

Comment: There is a website that use to guide angular updation 
https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=9.1-11.0 from there they will document step by step of the library, package updations